# DocumentEditor InsertBefore seems uncapable of finding a node in the document

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

I am devoloping a code refactor for Visual Studio using roslyn.

I am using the DocumentEditor class to remove some SyntaxNodes, and after removing them I am inserting some new ones. I am using a syntaxNode that I know I am not removing as reference to where I am inserting the new SyntaxNodes. But the editor doesn't seem able to find it when I use

```cs
foreach (var nodeToRemove in nodesToRemove)
{
    editor.RemoveNode(directive);
}

editor.InsertBefore(untouchedNode, newNodesToAdd); // No exception here, only when getting the new document
```

To debug it, I tried to find the reference node and then proceed as the Editor does

```cs
var ns = editor.OriginalRoot.DescendantNodesAndSelf().OfType<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault(); // ns is not null
var IshouldExist = editor.OriginalRoot.GetCurrentNode(ns); //it is null, weird
```

I have no idea why GetCurrentNode() returns null here.

In the stacktrace it came to my attention that the insertions are done in the changed document, I don't think this should be a problem because, if I do not try to insert the new nodes, the SytaxNode that I am using as reference is still in the changed document.

```
And throws an exception with the following stacktrace:
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.UsingDirectiveSyntax' to type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.MemberDeclarationSyntax'.
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__97`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index,IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxList`1.InsertRange(Int32 index,IEnumerable`1 nodes)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.SyntaxReplacer.NodeListEditor.VisitList[TNode](SyntaxList`1 list)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxRewriter.VisitCompilationUnit(CompilationUnitSyntax node)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.CompilationUnitSyntax.Accept[TResult](CSharpSyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxRewriter.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.SyntaxReplacer.BaseListEditor.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.SyntaxReplacer.NodeListEditor.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.SyntaxReplacer.InsertNodeInList(SyntaxNode root,SyntaxNode nodeInList,IEnumerable`1 nodesToInsert,Boolean insertBefore)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxNode.InsertNodesInListCore(SyntaxNode nodeInList,IEnumerable`1 nodesToInsert,Boolean insertBefore)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNodeExtensions.InsertNodesBefore[TRoot](TRoot root,SyntaxNode nodeInList,IEnumerable`1 newNodes)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeGeneration.CSharpSyntaxGenerator.InsertNodesBeforeInternal(SyntaxNode root,SyntaxNode declaration,IEnumerable`1 newDeclarations)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeGeneration.CSharpSyntaxGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass183_0.<InsertNodesBefore>b__0(SyntaxNode r)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing.SyntaxGenerator.PreserveTrivia[TNode](TNode node,Func`2 nodeChanger)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeGeneration.CSharpSyntaxGenerator.InsertNodesBefore(SyntaxNode root,SyntaxNode declaration,IEnumerable`1 newDeclarations)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing.SyntaxEditor.InsertChange.Apply(SyntaxNode root,SyntaxGenerator generator)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing.SyntaxEditor.GetChangedRoot()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing.DocumentEditor.GetChangedDocument()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered an issue much like this myself earlier today. I wasn't using a DocumentEditor, and was instead performing the actions in a more "Raw" nature on the Document object itself, however, when I was trying to sort Using Directives via a custom predicate, I noticed that if I purged all old Using Directives before inserting new usings, using the *.InsertBefore or *.InsertAfter, when the reference node is *not* a Using Directive, the whole system blows up. (It appears that internally it may be trying to treat the reference node as if it were a UsingDirectiveSyntax object, and then fails to compare it, but that is pure conjecture on my part, based upon the exception details...)

If you are working with a Document object which has no Using statements anymore, you will want to consider using a different approach to insert using statements:

```
List<UsingDirectiveSyntax> myNewUsingList = /* Construct Using List somehow */
NameSpaceDeclarationSyntax newNameSpace = myOldNameSpace.AddUsings(myUsingList);
CompilationUnitSyntax newCompileRootSyntax = (documentRoot as CompilationUnitSyntax).ReplaceNode(myOldNameSpace, newNameSpace);
return document.WithSyntaxRoot(newCompileRootSyntax);
```

This will be different than the semantics used when using a DocumentEditor instance, but as I am largely unfamiliar with node traversal on the current document being modified, I don't know how much help I can be when translating this separate approach to your needs.

This was sort of annoying code to write for me, as this approach is working upon immutable objects, so all of the above invoked above return a new instance of the object being manipulated, with the directed modifications by the method parameters implemented. The part of the code above,

```
document.WithSyntaxRoot(/*variable*/);
```

Creates a brand new Document() object, with internal data representing the changes from the old document to the new document, with all the replacements, insertions, deletions, etc. that you instigated with the prior code.

Based upon some preliminary spitballing with the DocumentEditor-based approach, using VS 2019's SDK Tools to create a CodeRefactoring project, the DocumentEditor approach may appear more like this:

```
DocumentEditor ed = await DocumentEditor.CreateAsync(document, cancellationToken);
NamespaceDeclarationSyntax nameSpace = ed.GetChangedRoot()
  .DescendantNodes()
  .FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetType() == typeof(NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)) as NamespaceDeclarationSyntax;

if (nameSpace != null)
{
  NamespaceDeclarationSyntax modifiedWithMyUsings = nameSpace.AddUsings(myUsingLists);
  ed.ReplaceNode(nameSpace, modifiedWithMyUsings);
}
```